# The ShadowOffset doesn't work on Android

Tags: react-native

I use the following style on a component:

```
const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 60,
        paddingTop: 15,
        shadowColor: '#000',//About the shadow setting
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },//About the shadow setting
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,//About the shadow setting
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize: 20
    }
};
```

The shadow doesn't get rendered.
[image]

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As A. Goodale said, shadow props are only for iOS. With Android, you can use `elevation` in your View style.

```
viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 60,
    paddingTop: 15,
    elevation: 4,
},
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props.html), the shadow props are only implemented on iOS.